# How to check if a string consists of 2 integers with a blank space in-between

Tags: java, string, integer

As the title states, i want to know how i can check if a string consists of 2 integers with a blank space in between them in Java. 
As an example: 
 
`0 2`, should return true. 
 
`0 abc`, should return false. 
 
`abcsd`, should return false. 
 
And so on...

If it is to any help, **I am getting my string from a text file with a buffered reader**. Maybe there is a more direct and easier way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you need to split the string check that there are enough substrings and then check each individual result. You will not get much love here without showing some code of an attempt to answer

Comment: What have you tried so far; besides asking other people to do your homework?

Comment: I have tried the following line of code: line.charAt(0) < P && line.charAt(2) < P && line.length() == 3, where P is the maximum integer is allowed to be

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `string.matches` method.

```
string.matches("\\d+\\s\\d+");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nZ3vV9/4)

- `\d+` matches one or more digits. So this asserts that the input string must contain a number at the start.
- `\s` matches a space character. So this asserts that the input string must contain a space at the middle.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits. So this asserts that the input string must contain a number at the end.
- Since `matches` method tries to match the whole input string, you don't need to add start and end anchors to your regex.

Comment: An obvious, elegant solution.  This ought to be accepted.

Comment: What does "\\d+\\s\\d+" mean in this case?

Comment: @KasperLederballeSørensen Numbers... _ Numbers.... It is a regular expression. Which is quite useful in these kind of cases.

Comment: I think if it's obvious someone is asking for homework help, then the answer should be something the professor may expect in their curriculum / level of study.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I am at a little roadblock now tho. I've looked at how to implement ranges in a regex, but i can't seem to get it to work.
my code is as follow: `if (s.matches("^[0-P]+\\s\\d+")) {}`
How can i restrict it to only return true if the number is in the range from 0 to P, where P is a local integer variable?

Comment: this regex solves the current question. If you have any further doubts, you could ask it as new question with valid and invalid examples.

Comment: @KasperLederballeSørensen you mean range from 0 to 9 or A to P . If yes, the try this `s.matches("^[0-9A-P]+\\s\\d+")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj no, i mean from 0 to a number P, that changes througout my program. P is a variable

Comment: i think this would work, `s.matches("[0-" +P +"]+\\s\\d+")`  , before that you need to convert the variable `P` to string.

Comment: It works, but only for single digits?

Comment: did you want to have a single digit number at the start?

Comment: It can be single digits, or multiple. Example `10 29`

Comment: @AvinashRaj mine fails, and it looks `s.matches("^[0-" + Integer.toString(P) + "]+\\s\\d+")`. If i for example use `20 1`, while `P = 5` it does not fail?

Comment: Why it would fail? in `20`, `2` falls within 0-5 and `0` falls within 0-5. So it returns true.

Comment: It should fail, because the highest the integer is allowed to be, is `P`, and if P is 5, then 20 is above that. That means it should fail

Comment: regex won't work like this. You need to use language default comparision operator.

Comment: So i should discard the regex solution?

Comment: yep, you should discard regex. But this should answer your current question. Since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Because you haven't posted your own code here, I assume that you haven't made much research into it, have you? First of all, will you use only 1-digit numbers? Here's how you should start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html